# Detail view without using a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I asked a related question that I realized was way over-complicated, so I made some design decicions and have simplified what I need to do here. I am using Xcode 5 and designing for iOS 7.

I have a navigation controller, a main menu (menuViewController) with a button, and a calculator (calculatorViewController) that is arrived at when the button on the main menu is clicked.

My Xcode storyboard is set up like this and it works perfectly (not an image, but I think this should be clear):

```
navigation controller -----> menuViewController ------> calculatorViewController
```

I would like to set up my main menu to have 3 buttons, each going to one of the following:
2 separate independent calculatorViewController units
1 other unrelated view

Because of the additional unrelated view, and because I don't think it makes sense for a few other design and content reasons, I do not want to use a UITable Master / Detail setup.

My question is how I might create a "duplicate" of my view and its code that can link to a second button on the main menu and run independently of the first. I know how to link the button from the main menu to the second instance of the view, but not how to create the second instance in the first place.

Of course, I want to conserve on memory, amount of code, and use best practices.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: It looks like this is unclear. I'm trying to figure out how to make it moreso.

Menu Buttons
button 1 ----> goes to calculator 1
button 2 ----> goes to calculator 2 (a second, identical, independent version of calculator 1)
button 3 ----> goes to another unrelated view

I know how to make the buttons get to the views. I am trying to figure out what the best way is to create the second calculator. Also, I want to make it clear that both of these calculators need to be able to run at the same time, and so both need to stay on the stack.

Thanks.

EDIT: Thanks for bearing with me.

Here is my code declaring the properties in my destination VC .h file:

```
// Properties for segue identifiers
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString *tankCalcOne;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString *tankCalcTwo;
```

Here is the code in the .m file for my menu / source VC:

```
// This allows the view for tankCalcOne or Two depending on which button is clicked in the menu

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"tankCalcOne"])
    {
        [[segue destinationViewController] TankCalculatorViewController:self];
    }
    else ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"tankCalcTwo"]);
    {
        [[segue destinationViewController] TankCalculatorViewController:self];
    }
}
```

I am getting 'No known instance instance method for selector TankCalculatorViewController' errors in both halves of my if/else statement. I can see why, since I haven't declared them, although I am not sure where I should declare them, as TankCalculatorViewController is the name of the view itself.

Comment: You're using storyboard? So you can drag on buttons and set segues?

Comment: You can connect segue from Mainvc to Detailvc and on button's click in Mainvc  set some bool or any variable of Detailvc in prepareforsegue to let Detailvc know which button is clicked and write code in viewDidLoad or any where else for apply changes according to button clicked in Detailvc.

Comment: @Wain I understand how to link the button to the calculator, as I indicated previously. What I do not know how to do is create a second separate / independent, identical calculator without copying all of the code and the storyboard elements. Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Is it not just 2 segues to the same controller with different data passed in prepare for segue? You haven't shown any code or storyboard, or described the differences between the calculators...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can't post an image of the storyboard because I don't have 10 reputation. I wish I could. It is exactly as described above.

One UINavigationController. One menu view controller that I have now set up with two buttons. I have set up two push segues in the storyboard editor to go to my calculatorView and have given them unique identifiers. I have not put any code whatsoever in my main menu view controller. I am stuck on point 3 of the suggestion in the answer below and have been looking for something that will solve this problem for the last few hours with no luck.

Comment: I want the calculators to be identical, as I said before, and I want them to operate exactly the same, but independent of one another. I just want each button on the menu view go to a copy of the calculator.

Comment: The calculator is coded and works perfectly, but none of that code pertains to this issue, which is why I haven't posted it. I am just looking for the code to cause the buttons to go to a separate copy of the calculator. If this is unclear, please let me know what else I can give you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a second instance. You do not have to use the push segue. If you use the push segue, it will automatically carry the navigationController. Use another segue or a custom one..

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not understanding what you are suggesting. How will creating another segue or a custom segue create a second calculator?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try explain how I would do this.

1. Create all needed segues and views/scenes in your storyboard (only one calculator scene with two segues leading to it)
2. Set different identifiers to your segues. This is important.
3. Create source code for your viewcontrollers and assign them to your storyboard's scenes (again only one calculator view controller with a property for you to specify mode)
4. In your menuViewController setup your `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` method.  Check `segue.identifier` in order to know which segue exactly is this (you set those in step 2). There in `segue.destinationViewController` variable you will get already created your target view controller so you can set calculatorViewController.useSecondVariant or whatever property you choose to use in order for your calculator to know its working mode.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In the reading I have been doing just now, I am starting to see what you guys are talking about as far as just setting up a second segue to the same VC. I am going to try working through this solution right now and see if I can get it to work. Something I see coming up is being able to change the Title in the nav bar for the new instance / calculator #2. Not quite sure how that would work seeing as how it is set in the storyboard editor for the ivew and I am using a different instance of the same view. Again, I appreciate the help. Going to try to hit this now.

Comment: Title should be easy. Leave it empty in the scene and set it in prepareForSegue using segue.destinationViewController.title for example. However I cannot try it right now.

Comment: Good looking out. I figured that would be something that would be pretty easy to tweak. Working on your suggestions now. Thanks!!!

Comment: OK. I got the additional segue set up and gave both of my segues for the two calculators different unique identifiers. I am at point 3 and do not quite understand what you mean. I am assuming I need to put the source code in the calculator VC file? I am not clear as to what you mean as far as specifying mode.

Comment: Yes, you put code in VC and set some property for mode. Next, in step 4 when you recognize segue by identifier you can set it and VC knows in which mode to operate

Comment: I have been researching since I got your original answer last night and cannot find an example of the code that you are talking about as far as setting a property for a mode in the calculator VC. I have seen the code for the segue method that goes in the menu VC, and I think I can tell how it is going to work as far as choosing one segue or the other using an if/else, but if there is any way that you could help me with the property code to select mode that would be much appreciated. Thanks for your continued help!

Comment: So from the class reference I am finding this. `@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString *identifier` Do I put two of these in my calculator's .h file, one for each of the segues?